# Perl extract matches from list

Tags: perl

I'm fairly new to perl but not to scripting languages. I have a file, and I'm trying to extract just one portion of each line that matches a regex. For example, given the file:

```
FLAG(123)
FLAG(456)
Not a flag
FLAG(789)
```

I'd like to extract the list [123, 456, 789]

The regex is obviously `/^FLAG\((\w+)/`. My question is, what's an easy way to extract this data in perl?

It's obviously not hard to set up a loop and do a bunch of `=~` matches, but I've heard quite a bit about perl's terseness and how it has an operator for everything, so I'm wondering if there's a slick, simple way to do this.

Also, can you point me towards a good perl reference where I can find out slick ways to do other things like this when the opportunity next arises? There are many perl resources on the web, but 90% of them are too simple and the other 10% I seem to lose the signal in the noise.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map` is your friend here.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Slurp;

my @matches = map { /^FLAG\((\w+)/ } read_file('file.txt');
```

Comment: Presumably this requires having the entire contents of `file.txt` in memory. Could be a problem with a large file. :-)

Comment: Cool. I didn't know that applying a regex results in the first match being returned. I imagine that if your regex has multiple match groups then the result would be a scalar of scalars? Thanks!

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure this one will work. First of all, in scalar context a regex returns a false value for non-match and a true value for match. In list context it will return the groups (or the matches if using the `g` option), but it will also return `undef` for no match. Won't `@matches` contain `undef` for all lines that don't match? I think you need a `grep` on top of this to keep out the cruft.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I would do it... Did you learn anything new and/or helpful?

```
my $file_name = "somefile.txt";
open my $fh, '<', $file_name or die "Could not open file $file_name: $!";

my @list;
while (<$fh>)
{
    push @list, $1 if /^FLAG\((\w+)/;
}
```

Things worth pointing out:

1. In a `while` loop condition (and ONLY in a while loop condition), reading from a filehandle will set the value to `$_` and check that the file was read automatically.
2. A statement can be modified by attaching an `if`, `unless`, `for`, `foreach`, `while`, or `until` to the end of it. Then it works as a conditional or loop on that one statement.
3. You probably know that regex capture groups are stored in `$1`, `$2`, etc., but you might not have known that the statement will work even if the statement has an `if` suffix. The `if` is evaluated first, so `push @list, $1 if /some_regex/` makes sense and will do the match first, assigning to `$1` before it is needed in the `push` statement.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have all of the data together in a single string:

```
my @matches = $data =~ /^FLAG\((\w+)/mg;
```

The `/g` modifier means to match as many times as possible, the `/m` makes `^` match after any newline (not only at the beginning of the string) and a match in list context returns all of the captures for all of those matches.

If you're reading the data in line-by-line then Platinum Azure's solution is the one you want.

Comment: +1 for accounting for the single string case, which I didn't think of.